# Using try catch on FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a question regarding FileNotFoundExcpetion. The interface I have got defined the method name including "throws FileNotFoundExcpetion".

```
public static void writeAssignment(ArrayList<String> assignment, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename);
        for (String str : assignment) {
            writer.write(str + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to handle the exception? When I am writing to a file I am creating with the filewriter, how is it possible that the file wouldnt be found if I am creating the file in the method??

Comment: Your function never throws a `FileNotFoundException`, you're catching it, so declaring it as `throws FileNotFoundException` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a bit misleading name. Here it will be thrown when a file could not be created. The answers will mention that you should simply throw IOException as FileNotFoundException actually is an IOException. Leave it to the caller to handle anything disruptive.

Comment: I could be wrong but what about th scenario where the path provided doesn't exist? Example `E:\abc` but there is no E drive mounted on the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IOException` is a super class of `FileNotFoundException`. Therefore your catch block for `IOException` also catches every `FileNotFoundException`.

You should implement the function as follows:

```
public static void writeAssignment(ArrayList<String> assignment, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename)) {
        for (String str : assignment) {
            writer.write(str + "\n");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw e; // catch and re-throw
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch Exception instead of IOException

```
public static void writeAssignment(ArrayList<String> assignment, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename);
    for (String str : assignment) {
        writer.write(str + "\n");
    }
    writer.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

From this type coding, you can see/learn the hierarchy of exceptions.
If you want to execute your program whether caught exception or not, you can use **finally** block. Where you will close your writer.